# Is there a light weight version of Adobe Illustrator or something similar?

Tags: software-rec, graphics

I am a developer but need to create some graphics! I have the Adobe Illustrator trial which is about to expire. Is there any other application which is less expensive and have the same features as Adobe Illustrator?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) is more than enough for the dabbler, and has quite a decent number of features for professionals as well.

Comment: HOLY COW! Inkscape looks amazing!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Ignacio that InkScape is the only free alternative.

A good commercial alternative is the not too-costly and well-noted [Xara Xtreme](http://www.xara.com/us/products/designer) ($89).

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of googling I came accross the following softwares which you might want to try out:

- **Xara** for linux (http://www.xaraxtreme.org)
- **Inkscape** for windows, mac and linux (http://www.inkscape.org)
- **Skencil** for linux and unix (http://www.skencil.org)